# magento 2 - Product Tax Class and Taxable Goods

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class

New in Magento 2, Trying to assign tax zones and rates to Taxable Goods I cannot find in admin the place to do that.

Anyone knows where I can find Product Tax Class (like in Magento 1) to assign tax zones and rates to taxable goods?.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you create new Tax Rules, you can click to "Additional Settings" to create new tax class
[image]

Comment: They've done a fantastic job of making that impossible to find.